# How is this page designed to load view?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm having hard time understanding how this page is being loaded.
While using inspect code I can view different divs but when I click on view source i dont see any div or elements.

https://outlook.live.com/owa/

view-source:https://outlook.live.com/owa/

Can you please explain how they are using js and iframe to load it?

Comment: That page uses React. To see the actual live source, right-click any part of the page and click "inspect". Or install the React developer tools extensions for your browser and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is rendered by the client side. Look this https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-exactly-is-client-side-rendering-and-hows-it-different-from-server-side-rendering-bd5c786b340d

Comment: Thanks. The link explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is called One Page Application. 
Just open developer mode in your browser(F12 for chrome) and go to network tab. you should see that the real data traffic between the page and server is there. The page you see is a single page that loads the data on the client side